# How to restrict in PostgreSQL (using SQL and PL/pgSQL) way of changing table data only by means of certain stored procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, restriction

Need to allow data changes in a table only through specially created for this stored procedures.

I thought about using triggers as one of possible ways to implement such restriction. Anyway want to do it most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

REVOKE everything for everybody on this table and GRANT the usage of that function. This function should be created with SECURITY DEFINER. The definer must be the only role that has access to this table, for example the owner of the table.